# laravel で使われている ?? の意味を教えてください

Tags: php, laravel

下記のコードで使われている`??`はどういう意味か教えてください。

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();
    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ja/migration70.new-features.php
Null 合体演算子

左辺が nullでなければ 右辺の値を返します

laravelではなく、phpの関数です